# Double linked list API design in C

Tags: c, linked-list, api, library

I have created the following few functions for handling the use of doubly linked lists.

list.c:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* all functions returning a pointer return NULL on failure
 * all functions returning an integer return != 0 on failure
 */

//internal
 static struct node {
        struct node *previous;
        size_t len;
        void *data;
        uint8_t greedy_data;
        struct node *next;
};

//internal
struct node *find_node(LIST *list, uint16_t index);

// creates linked list instance (metadata grouping) with one node
LIST *create_list(void)
{
        LIST *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
        if (!ret)
                return NULL;
        ret->start = malloc(sizeof(*ret->start));
        if (!ret->start) {
                free(ret);
                return NULL;
        }
        ret->node_count = 1;
        ret->end = ret->start;
        return ret;
}

//frees all internal memory associate with list
void destroy_list(LIST *list)
{
        struct node *tmp = list->start;
        for (;;list->node_count--) {
                if (tmp->greedy_data)
                        free(tmp->data);
                if (list->node_count == 1) {
                        free(tmp);
                        break;
                }
                tmp = tmp->next;
                free(tmp->previous);
        }
        free(list);
}

/* creates new node, appending it to the end of the list if
 * index < 0 or index == list->node_count; returns 1 on 
 * invalid index or malloc() failure
 */
int add_node(LIST *list, int32_t index)
{
        if (index > list->node_count || list->node_count == UINT16_MAX - 1)
                return 1;
        struct node *add = malloc(sizeof(*add));
        if (!add)
                return 1;
        add->greedy_data = 0;
        if (index < 0 || index == list->node_count) {
                add->previous = find_node(list, list->node_count - 1);
                add->previous->next = add;
                list->end = add;
                list->node_count++;
                return 0;
        }
        add->next = find_node(list, index);
        add->previous = add->next->previous;
        add->next->previous = add;
        add->previous->next = add;
        list->node_count++;
    return 0;
}

/* frees internal memory associated with the node at index,
 * decrements list->node_count, and adjusts link pointers
 */
int rm_node(LIST *list, int32_t index)
{
        if (index < 0)
                index = list->node_count - 1;
        struct node *goner = find_node(list, index);
        if (!goner)
                return 1;
        goner->previous->next = goner->next;
        goner->next->previous = goner->previous;
        if (goner->greedy_data)
                free(goner->data);
        free(goner);
        list->node_count--;
        return 0;
}

/* associates node->data at the node in list at index with the data supplied
 * as well as node->len with len; a true value of hands_off indicates that API 
 * should be "greedy" with the data, keeping a copy internally so the user 
 * doesn't have to worry about it (the API will free it, provided the user calls
 * rm_struct node() or destroy_list())
 */
int bind_node(LIST *list, uint16_t index, void *data, size_t len, bool hands_off)
{
        struct node *tmp = find_node(list, index);
        if (!tmp)
                return 1;
        tmp->len = len;
        if (hands_off) {
                tmp->data = malloc(len);
                if (!tmp->data)
                        return 1;
                memcpy(tmp->data, data, len);
                tmp->greedy_data = 1;
        }
        else {
                tmp->data = data;
        }
        return 0;
}

//a small layer of abstraction returning the data pointer of a node
void *access_node(LIST *list, uint16_t index)
{
        struct node *tmp = find_node(list, index);
        if (!tmp)
                return NULL;
        return tmp->data;
}

//internal function returning struct node* based on index
struct node *find_node(LIST *list, uint16_t index)
{
        if (index >= list->node_count)
                return NULL;
        if (index < list->node_count / 2) {
                struct node *ret = list->start;
                for (; index > 0; index--)
                        ret = ret->next;
                return ret;
        } else {
                struct node *ret = list->end;
                for (; list->node_count - 1 - index > 0; index++)
                        ret = ret->previous;
                return ret;
        }
}
```

list.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    struct node *start;
    struct node *end;
    uint16_t node_count;
} LIST;

LIST *create_list (void);
void destroy_list (LIST *list);
int  add_node     (LIST *list, int32_t index);
int  rm_node      (LIST *list, int32_t index);
int  bind_node    (LIST *list, uint16_t index, void *data, size_t len, bool hands_off);
void *access_node (LIST *list, uint16_t index);
```

Though I obviously welcome suggestions and critiques on performance, style, etc., my main question is about the design of the interface. Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how it could be designed to be more useful, usable, or clear?
Disclaimer: I haven't passed it through Valgrind et al yet, so I'm not too positive it's completely bug/mem-leak free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my main question is about the design of the interface. Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how it could be designed to be more useful, usable, or clear?

**Drop the `struct` definition from list.h**

Better hide such unneeded details from the user.  Consider only the declaration of `struct list`.

```
typedef struct list LIST;
```

If the user needs access to a `struct` member, provide it through helper functions.

**Use `const`**

For functions which do not change the list. See below.

**Namespace impact**

Consider a more localized naming scheme to make clear what comes from list.h

```
// example
// list.h --> dlist.h

typedef struct dlist_s dlist;

list *dlist_create(void);
void dlist_destroy(dlist *list);
int dlist_add_node(dlist *list, int32_t index);
int dlist_rm_node(dlist *list, int32_t index);
int dlist_bind_node(dlist *list, uint16_t index, void *data, size_t len, bool hands_off);
void *dlist_access_node(const dlist *list, uint16_t index);
```

**Move function descriptions to .h**

Consider the .c file is opaque to the user.

**Good that .h only includes needed std headers**

**Questionable index type**

Why `uint16_t, int32_t index` vs. `unsigned index` or `size_t index`?

**Missing code guard**

[What exactly do C include guards do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810115/what-exactly-do-c-include-guards-do)

---

Good use of `#include "list.h"` as first include file in list.c

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, especially the use of `const` (completely missed that) and moving the struct definition of `list`. BTW, the index is int32_t when `< 0` is needed (see inline comments). As for the `uint16_t` index, the maximum number of nodes is `2^16 - 1` (see list definition). I thought it better to make the size explicit so the compiler could warn about trying to use e.g. index 70000. Is this reasoning sound, or is there a better way?

Comment: Oh, and as this is merely a thought exercise, I'm not going to bother with namespace resolution or include guards. The advantages of non-production code :).

Comment: @user692992 Re: " better way? " with special meaning to `index < 0`, recommend another function like `add_node_end(LIST *list)` and use `size_t index` elsewhere.  Plan for success (wide code re-use) and do artificially  limit indexing to 16-bit.

Comment: Thanks; that;s a good idea

Comment: @user692992  Oops, meant "... and do _not_ artificially limit indexing to 16-bit."

Comment: Yeah I figured lol

Comment: And if you don't mind answering another question, would you suggest `inline`ing the `accesss_node()` call?

Comment: As `access_node()` is meant for user use. to make inline codes needs to un-hide the `struct` def   - something that I'd rather avoid..  I'd suspect your overall application will not notice an appreciable difference as `inline` or not`.